# Customized ThreadPoolExecutor to execute some tasks concurrently and some in queue

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, swingworker, threadpoolexecutor

I am creating an MVP application with Java Swing. I need to execute various `Tasks` that are instances of a `Task`class, I created extending `SwingWorker` class!

I came across `Executors` class but none of the provided executors seem to fulfil my needs.

I want to execute some of my `Task` instances concurrently and some of my `Task` instances in queue. Also, I want a method invocation when all tasks have been completed. Like, `done` method in `SwingWorker` class!

```
abstract class CustomExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {

    CustomExecutor(Collection<Task> synchronousTasks, Collection<Task> asynchronousTasks) {
        // .........
    }

    // To be called when all tasks have been executed successfully!
    abstract void done();

}
```

I have not used `ExecutorService` or `ThreadPoolExecutor` before and unable to come up with any solution!

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to execute some of my Task instances Synchronously (concurrently) and some of my Task instances Asynchronously (in queue)."? "Synchronous" is very different from "concurrent" and "asychronous" has nothing to do with queueing. Can you elaborate/provide an example?

Comment: Pardon for creating confusion! I've edited the question! I need some tasks to be executed "concurrently" and some "in queue (one after another)!

Answer (score 0):

Let's briefly compare the two solutions you mentioned - `SwingWorker` and `Executors` framework. The general idea behind the two solutions is similar, but depending on the use case one can be better over the other.

**SwingWorker**

- executes asynchronously the logic implemented in the `doInBackground` method.
- you need to subclass `SwingWorker` to implement the logic
- there are some useful methods to integrate with Swing and update the UI in the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) - `publish()`, `process()`, `done()`, `get/setProgress()` and some property change listener support methods.
- a single instance of `SwingWorker` corresponds to a single task
- when you invoke `SwingWorker.execute()`, internally the worker instance submits *itself* as a task (`Callable`) to an `ExecutorService` (to be precise - a `ThreadPoolExecutor`) so that the logic implemented in the `doInBackground` method is executed asynchronously in a separate thread
- there is a default configuration of the `ThreadPoolExecutor` used by all the `SwingWorker` objects you ever create, hidden in the `SwingWorker` class. If you want to provide your own `ExecutorService` for executing the `SwingWorker`s, you can do so by setting `sun.awt.AppContext.getAppContext().put(SwingWorker.class, yourOwnExecutorService)`. However, as I said, you can have only one global `ExecutorService` for all the `SwingWorker`s in your application.
- to summarize: `SwingWorker` hides the concurrency details from you, but exposes API to communicate with the Swing UI. Use `SwingWorker` if your tasks first need to do some computation in the background and then update the UI.
- More about [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

**Executors framework**

- You are in full control of the `ExecutorService` configuration - there are utility methods in the [`Executors`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) class to create some common configurations or you can instantiate a `ThreadPoolExecutor` yourself.
- The framework is generic - it accepts any `Runnable`/`Callable` tasks, which may perform any logic. There is no special support for Swing.
- You need to [shutdown](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown--) the `ExecutorService` yourself.
- More about [Executors Framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html)

If I understand your requirement correctly, you might prefer to use  `ExecutorService` rather than `SwingWorker`, so that you have more control over the concurrency. Submit the tasks that you want to be queued (ie. executed sequentially) to an executor created with `Executors#newSingleThreadExecutor()`. For the tasks that you want to be executed concurrently, use a different `ExecutorService` - created with `Executors#newCachedThreadPool()`, `Executors#newFixedThreadPool(int)` or a custom `ThreadPoolExecutor`. See Javadocs to check which fits your needs best.

You can use `ExecutorService#invokeAll()` to submit multiple tasks at once **and to block** until they are done or you can call `ExecutorService#submit()` in a loop to submit them one by one without blocking and at a later moment call `Future.get()` on the `Future` obtained from `submit()` to block until the execution is done.

Once you have called `get()` on all futures - both those corresponding to `synchronousTasks` and `asynchronousTasks`, you know that all are done and you can call your `done()` method.

If you want to learn even more, I recommend reading the Javadocs and the source code of [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html), [`Executor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) and [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) classes.